# Can 32 bit application run on 64 bit operating system after 5 GB ram usage

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

If 5 GB or RAM is used out of 8 GB and then if i want to run a application which is 32 bit compatible then can it run on this computer in this scenario?

Comment: Why not? Try it as long as you machine takes that much.

Comment: 32 bit system can allocate upto 4 GB of RAM .Then if the application is 32 bit then how can it run .explain it please . @Biswa

Comment: The OS handles the RAM allocation, not the app.

Comment: Already answered, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes you can

Long answer: Applications (as opposed to the OS kernel components) do not see the "real" (or physical) memory layout. The Computer's MMU is instructed by the OS to create a unique "fake" (or virtual) memory layout for the application, that is essentially empty. The process will simply not see the RAM that is already used (apart from Statistics)